# Retrieve product custom option

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, custom-options

I have a **custom option** for a **product**. I would like to retrieve that data after add to cart is pressed but before the product is actually added to the cart. 
[image]

I want the data '12345'.

I used the checkout_cart_add event observer but I can't get the product as a variable in the observer.php file because the product hasn't been added to the cart yet.

Custom option added from admin backend.
[image]

What event should I use? and what function to use to get this custom option data?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During **addToCart** request, you can get the data you want this way

```
print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams());
```

This should return something like

```
Array
(
    [uenc] => ...
    [product] => ...
    [form_key] => ...
    [related_product] => 
    [options] => Array
        (
            [XXXX] => YYYY
        )
)
```

Where YYYY inside "options" in this example should be the value you want (12345 in your example), XXXX should be the custom option id

This should work in your observer, as `Mage::app()->getRequest()` can be accessed there, or maybe you'd want to use some generic controller_action event... not sure **why** you need to do your thing **before** product is added to cart, so it's your choice

Comment: Nice. Glad it helped